# MVC3, Using OpenIdPortableArea, UriFormatException when using the login widget

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth, mvccontrib

My question is, why, when I click on the button for openid that I added to my site with teh procedure below, do I get:

```
[UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.]
 System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind) +6235084
 System.Uri..ctor(String uriString) +20
 OpenIdPortableArea.Areas.OpenId.Controllers.OpenIdController.GetAppRoot(HttpRequestBase request) +202
 OpenIdPortableArea.Areas.OpenId.Controllers.OpenIdController.GetCallBackUrl(String url) +182
 OpenIdPortableArea.Areas.OpenId.Controllers.OpenIdController.Login(LoginInput loginInput) +120
```

I think the URI it doesn't understand is the callback url it's forming, like it doesn't know what my site is?  But that's just a guess from the stack trace.

What I did:

I'm using MVC3 on .Net 4.

I installed OpenIdPortableArea ([documentation](http://openidportablearea.codeplex.com/documentation)) by

```
 PM> Install-Package OpenIdPortableArea.RazorViews
```

In a just-created MVC project.  And that went fine.  I removed from web.config:

```
<section name="uri" type="System.Configuration.UriSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, ...
```

Since in .Net 4 I believe that's taken care of in machine.config (and having it in there caused an internal server error once deployed).  Then I created the Message handlers, verbatim from docs, and put these calls into Application_Start

```
  MvcContrib.Bus.AddMessageHandler(typeof(ClaimsRequestMessageHandler));
  MvcContrib.Bus.AddMessageHandler(typeof(AuthenticatedMessageHandler));
```

I replaced the content of the stock _LoginPartial.cshtml with:

```
  @using  OpenIdPortableArea.UI
  @Html.LoginStatusWidget()
```

So now when I get click login, I get the logos, and can type in my open Id or click on the icon for yahoo, google, aol, myopenid... but they all give me the error above.  I think I haven't done whatever I need to do to tell OpenIdPortableArea the base url of my site?

(dotnet openaugh and mvc contrib are underptinning of OpenIdPortableArea, to explain the tagging)

Comment: Likely a recent bug in the library, possibly fixed.

Comment: Also, you don't need to call AddMessageHandler anymore. PortableAreas now register their own message handlers automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from a bug in the library, which is fixed now in the latest version ([2.0.0.2 available now on NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/OpenIdPortableArea.RazorViews)). The bug had to do with building the return URL to send to the OpenID provider.